# Using a VBA Dialog Box when closing a SpreadSheet

Tags: vba, excel

I would like a dialog box to appear when someone attempts to close an important Excel sheet. Namely I would like it to ask "Have you logged all Changes?" giving them the opportunity to click "Yes" or "No". If they click "Yes" the sheet will close, but if they Click "No" it will ask them to "Please log all changes in the Change Notes section".

Any and all help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try putting your code in the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event handler. Post your code if you get stuck. Or, if you're already stuck, post the code you're currently having problems implementing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code you are looking for. It asks the question, and if No is clicked, it cancels the closing of the workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    ureply = MsgBox("Have you Saved All Changes?", vbYesNo)

    If ureply = vbNo Then
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This code needs to go on 'ThisWorkbook' (Shown above the word 'Modules') on your VBA editor